# What is wrong with this JavaScript clear function code?

Tags: javascript

Why the clear function doesn't work. 
I am not sure what I am doing wrong?
Any help is appreciated.
Regards
Yusuf

```
    function StringBuilder(initials) {
      var list = [];
      if (initials) {
        list.push(initials);
      }
      return {
        append: function (str) {
          if (!str) {
            str = "";
          }
          list.push(str);
          return this;
        },
        appendLine: function (str) {
          if (!str) {
            str = "";
          }
          list.push(str + "\n");
          return this;
        },
        clear: function () {
          this.list = [];
          return this;
        },
        toString: function () {
          return list.toString().replace(/,/g, " ");
        }
      };
    }
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is vague.  Can you describe specifically what's happening?

Comment: It doesn't clear the list

Comment: Why are you returning this? also please show how you are calling your code.

Comment: @ngeksyo probably so he can write `sb.append("hello").append("world")`

Comment: I saw the issue, on the clear function remove this. in the this.list = []

Answer (score 2):

Your `clear()` method resets `this.list`, but `list` is not an object property; it's a variable in the closure. The code should be just

```
    clear: function () {
      list = [];
      return this;
    },
```

Comment: Also note that `list.join("")` is a little shorter than calling `.toString()` and `.replace()`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint as well

Comment: Also, what is the difference between var sb = new StringBuilder() and var sb = StringBuilder() ?

Comment: @YusufCelik there is no difference, because your function always returns a new object.